# How to make Jquery Mobile 1.3 ListView(Only) to Right To Left(R2L)?

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile, jquery-mobile-listview

I have the following html,

http://jsfiddle.net/yWkGR/2/

```
<div data-role="page">

    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>My Title</h1>
    </div><!-- /header -->

    <div data-role="content" id="content">    
        <ul data-role="listview">
                    <li>

        <a href="#">
            <img width="80" height"80" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7efa2e4098f60c15d230436ca99d7250?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
            <div class="left">
                <h3>New Latest One</h3>
                <p>$12,000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" style="width:75px"/>
            </div>
            </a>
            </li>
              <li>

        <a href="#">
            <img width="80" height"80" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7efa2e4098f60c15d230436ca99d7250?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
            <div class="left">
                <h3>New Latest One</h3>
                <p>$12,000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" style="width:75px"/>
            </div>
            </a>
            </li>
              <li>

        <a href="#">
            <img width="80" height"80" src="http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/7efa2e4098f60c15d230436ca99d7250?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG" />
            <div class="left">
                <h3>New Latest One</h3>
                <p>$12,000</p>
            </div>
            <div class="right">
                <input type="text" style="width:75px"/>
            </div>
            </a>
            </li>
        </ul>

    </div><!-- /content -->

</div><!-- /page -->
```

The problem is that I need this html to be right to left for my users. Can this is possible without using any third party library?

[image]

Comment: Everything or just the text?

Comment: @Gajotres, Actually I am doing this for multilingual support. So, I need to the list to right instead of left, so it look decent in arabic/urdu/hebrew languages

Comment: @Gajotres, Starting from right to left, image, text , textbox and finally icon

Comment: Here it is, even text box input is inverted :D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Solution

Only css used, working jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/Ajdc4/

You will only need to change icon. I can't do it from here.

```
.ui-input-text {
    width: 75px;
}

#custom-li .ui-li .ui-btn-text .ui-link-inherit .ui-li-thumb {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
    right: 0;
    margin-right: 0 !important;
} 

#custom-li .ui-li .ui-icon {
    left: 10px !important;    
}

#custom-li .ui-li .ui-btn-text .ui-link-inherit .left {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 50px;
    display:block; 
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform:matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);    
}

#custom-li .ui-li .ui-btn-text .ui-link-inherit .right {
    float: right;
    margin-right: 20px;
    display:block; 
    -moz-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -webkit-transform: matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
    -o-transform:matrix(-1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);        
}


#left-split-icon {
    left: 0 !important;   
    border-width: 0 1px 0 0 !important;
}

.ui-li-link-alt { right: auto !important; } // Fix for jQM 1.3
```

## More info

If you want to learn how to do this kind of changes by yourself you should check this **[article](http://www.gajotres.net/learn-how-to-customize-jquery-mobile-application/)**, it will teach you how to do this by yourself.

Comment: Thanks. But it's not correct. Ses this for example, http://www.intlaqa.com/jquery-mobile-rtl/rtl.jquery.mobile-1.2.0/index.htm Actually it is very big and not work for me.

Comment: You should have said you need a split button listview, this is something completely different.

Comment: Can you please look at the site I have given? At the bottem you will find the listview http://i.stack.imgur.com/qhG54.png The text is not revert.

Comment: And where is the difference? What is the difference? If you remove the input box you will get the same example.

Comment: Just undo changes on text, he don't want reverted text :) Because Arabic text is inverted to us, but is not physically inverted, just as font :)

Comment: Tnx I will fix it, that's called ups :)

Comment: This should be it. I didn't meant any disrespect.

Comment: Bar sam ga ja tako skontao, možda grešim :) Ono, unos teksta jeste s desna na levo, ali ne znam da li to keyboard input na OS automatski prilagodi. Valjda. Nisam imao kontakta sa tim :)

Comment: Hvala na komentaru, nije da njihov jezik koristim iz dana u dan ;)

Comment: @jqm see this , only icon is not working why in my app http://i.stack.imgur.com/uGIHK.png

Comment: Sorry I don't understand you?

Comment: @Gajotres, actuallly I have copy paste your code but the small icon is still on right. see this image http://i.stack.imgur.com/uGIHK.png

Comment: You probably forgot to add  id="left-split-icon" to the a tag for a split button. Open my example and search HTML, look for  id="left-split-icon".

Comment: @Gajotres, No. I have checked.I am seeing that left: 0 is applied

Comment: Maybe some of your css is interfering with this? As you can see it is working in my example.

Comment: @Gajotres, I have found the issue that in jquery mobile 1.3 there is right : 0 which stopping the left:0 to work. I have added this and it works `.ui-li-link-alt {
    right: auto !important;
}` Better if you update your answer, so that other users take the advantage